# SPDataSource and updatecommand in SharePoint 2010

Tags: list

I'm able to use an SPDataSource to get read only data using the Select Command. But I have not been able to find a solution for adding data to a list using SPDataSource.

How do I use the UpdateCommand with SPDataSource to update fields in SharePoint 2010 lists?